# In AngularJs, how to .get an object with nested objects from the database

Tags: mongodb, angularjs

I'm trying to get an object from MongoDB, the object has a nested object inside it (in this case the _id):

```
{_id:{$oid: 1234567}, title:'The title', content:'The content'},
{_id:{$oid: 8910111}, title:'different title', content:'different content'}, ...
```

Whenever i try to do a get via the angularjs-mongolab resource :

```
$scope.post = Posts.get({title: 'The title'}, function () {alert('loaded')});
```

It gives me a `TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'` because its for some reason returning an array. When i do a `.query` instead of a `.get` with the same arguments, it returns the whole collection but with the `_id` returning a blank object `{}`

I think this is discussed on the angular github issues page [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1044) but i cant seem to relate this to my case. Anybody spotting anything wrong?

Comment: The problem is `_id:{$oid = 1234567}` is not JSon, so the serialization doesn't work. The correct Json should be `_id:{$oid: 1234567}`

Comment: Sorry about that, it's supposed to be `:` . i'm just generalizing for this question, the actual object is being served by mongolab so it serves it in the right format.

Comment: How about if you do `Posts.get({title: 'The title'}, function () {alert('loaded')})[0]`, can you try that?

Comment: strangely, i made it work by using `Posts.get({id: 1234567}), function() {alert('loaded')});` how did `_id.$oid` get mapped to just `id`? will try your solution